# React: How to handle components/state inside single page application?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I developing a Sharepoint Online Form  which is using react. Sharepoint Online uses single page like navigation, meaning no real page reload/refresh.

The form loads data vi a http request. But the state is showing containing old data. Only after hard refresh/cache clear the state contains the correct data.

My issues is that due to the navigation my react state is not getting properly updated. I'm getting data async:

```
  public componentDidMount(): void {
    this._renderListAsync();
  }
```

`_renderListAsync()` makes a http requests and sets the state:

```
._renderListAsync()
   .get("xxx.xxx.xxx") // HTTP request
   .then((response) => {
        this.setState({item:response});
  }
```

The intent is to load data every time the users goes to the site.

When I clear the cache and hard reload my states is updated to the correct one.

But when the users navigates back and forth between different sites React just adds more componentet:

[image]

Is this intended?

How can I make sure the state is being updated correctly and that i unmount old components?

Comment: Can you describe how `_renderListAsync()` sets the state?

Comment: Added pesudo code to show the `_renderListAsync()`.

Comment: `componentDidMount()` is executed just once when a component is rendered for the first time. You need to completely remove your component not just hiding it in order to execute the fetch again

Comment: How can I completely remove it?